# Merely loading bootstrap is breaking animation parameters

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to implement a frontend code found online for rolling a dice.

The code can be found in this repository: https://codesandbox.io/s/xjk3xqnprw?file=/styles.css:0-4535

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Dice Roll</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dice">
      <ol class="die-list even-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-1">
        <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
      </ol>
      <ol class="die-list odd-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-2">
        <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="roll-button">Roll Dice</button>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#545454, #454545, #676767);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.dice {
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(8rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  perspective: 600px;
}
.die-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  height: 6rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 6rem;
}
.even-roll {
  transition: transform 1.5s ease-out;
}
.odd-roll {
  transition: transform 1.25s ease-out;
}
.die-item {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: inset -0.35rem 0.35rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    inset 0.5rem -0.25rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two three"
    "four five six"
    "seven eight nine";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.dot {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #676767;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -0.15rem 0.15rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  height: 1.25rem;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 1.25rem;
}
.even-roll[data-roll="1"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="2"] {
  transform: rotateX(450deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="3"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="4"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(810deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="5"] {
  transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="6"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(900deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="1"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="2"] {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="3"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-810deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="4"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-630deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="5"] {
  transform: rotateX(-450deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="6"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-900deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
[data-side="1"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="2"] {
  transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="3"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="4"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="5"] {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="6"] {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="1"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: four;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: six;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-area: nine;
}

button {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  justify-self: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .dice {
    perspective: 1300px;
  }
}
```

I tried to incorporate the code in my web project (which uses bootstrap5) but the dice images render incorrectly. After some trial and error, I found that merely loading bootstrap in the same page as above is the cause of the error. the page renders like this:
[image: wrongly rendered page]

The code for rendering this page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Dice Roll</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
          EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dice">
      <ol class="die-list even-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-1">
        <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
      </ol>
      <ol class="die-list odd-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-2">
        <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="roll-button">Roll Dice</button>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I imagine that bootstrap sets some config that is causing this behaviour. Could anyone help me identify them so that I can override them in my app and allow the animation to be displayed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "problem" here is indeed the bootstrap styling.
Add this line to fix your code `box-sizing: content-box;`

Here:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    box-sizing: content-box;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Dice Roll</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-
          EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            box-sizing: content-box;
        }
        html {
            font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
        }
        body {
            background: linear-gradient(#545454, #454545, #676767);
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .dice {
            align-items: center;
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 2rem;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(8rem, 1fr));
            grid-template-rows: auto;
            justify-items: center;
            padding: 2rem;
            perspective: 600px;
        }
        .die-list {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr;
            height: 6rem;
            list-style-type: none;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            width: 6rem;
        }
        .even-roll {
            transition: transform 1.5s ease-out;
        }
        .odd-roll {
            transition: transform 1.25s ease-out;
        }
        .die-item {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            box-shadow: inset -0.35rem 0.35rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
            inset 0.5rem -0.25rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            display: grid;
            grid-column: 1;
            grid-row: 1;
            grid-template-areas:
    "one two three"
    "four five six"
    "seven eight nine";
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
            height: 100%;
            padding: 1rem;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .dot {
            align-self: center;
            background-color: #676767;
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: inset -0.15rem 0.15rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            display: block;
            height: 1.25rem;
            justify-self: center;
            width: 1.25rem;
        }
        .even-roll[data-roll="1"] {
            transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
        .even-roll[data-roll="2"] {
            transform: rotateX(450deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
        .even-roll[data-roll="3"] {
            transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
        .even-roll[data-roll="4"] {
            transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(810deg) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
        .even-roll[data-roll="5"] {
            transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
        .even-roll[data-roll="6"] {
            transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(900deg) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
        .odd-roll[data-roll="1"] {
            transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
        }
        .odd-roll[data-roll="2"] {
            transform: rotateX(-270deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
        }
        .odd-roll[data-roll="3"] {
            transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-810deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
        }
        .odd-roll[data-roll="4"] {
            transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-630deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
        }
        .odd-roll[data-roll="5"] {
            transform: rotateX(-450deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
        }
        .odd-roll[data-roll="6"] {
            transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-900deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
        }
        [data-side="1"] {
            transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
        }
        [data-side="2"] {
            transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
        }
        [data-side="3"] {
            transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
        }
        [data-side="4"] {
            transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
        }
        [data-side="5"] {
            transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
        }
        [data-side="6"] {
            transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg) translateZ(4rem);
        }
        [data-side="1"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
            grid-area: five;
        }
        [data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
            grid-area: one;
        }
        [data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
            grid-area: nine;
        }
        [data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
            grid-area: one;
        }
        [data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
            grid-area: five;
        }
        [data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
            grid-area: nine;
        }
        [data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
            grid-area: one;
        }
        [data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
            grid-area: three;
        }
        [data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
            grid-area: seven;
        }
        [data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
            grid-area: nine;
        }
        [data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
            grid-area: one;
        }
        [data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
            grid-area: three;
        }
        [data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
            grid-area: five;
        }
        [data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
            grid-area: seven;
        }
        [data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
            grid-area: nine;
        }
        [data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
            grid-area: one;
        }
        [data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
            grid-area: three;
        }
        [data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
            grid-area: four;
        }
        [data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
            grid-area: six;
        }
        [data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
            grid-area: seven;
        }
        [data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(6) {
            grid-area: nine;
        }

        button {
            align-self: center;
            background-color: #efefef;
            border: none;
            color: #333;
            font-size: 1.25rem;
            font-weight: 700;
            justify-self: center;
            padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        }
        button:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        @media (min-width: 900px) {
            .dice {
                perspective: 1300px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dice">
    <ol class="die-list even-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-1">
        <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="die-list odd-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-2">
        <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
<button type="button" id="roll-button">Roll Dice</button>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great! That surely does the job! Now, suppose I want to insert this code inside a container in my bootstrap template. How can I adjust the code so that it renders correctly? adding the *{} styling messes up the whole page and adding all the styles inside *{} to the container also doesn't work.

Comment: you could add this instead: .dice *{box-sizing: content-box;}
Every element in your class dice has now the correct box-sizing

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!